# Multiple vs Multi

Tags: word-usage

What is the usage difference between "multiple" and "multi"?
I have an algorithm that uses more than one agent. Should I call it multi-agent or multiple-agents algorithm?

Comment: Under rare exceptions, an adjective should not be plural. Six million dollar man. Not *six million dollars man*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Multi* is a prefix meaning "more than one" or "having or involving many". So you can safely use "multi-agent" as an adjective.

When you use a hyphen to make an adjective, as a rule, you must place the singular noun form after it. For instance, you can say *32-bit word* and not *32-bits word*. Although you can say a computer word has 32 bits in it (without hyphen).

References:

### [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English](http://www.ldoceonline.com/)

***[multi-](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/multi-)***

```
more than one:
 - multicoloured
 - a multistorey office block
```

### [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/)

[***multi-***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multi)

```
1) many :  multiple :  much 
 - multivalent

2) more than two 
 - multilateral

3) more than one 
 - multiparous
 - multibillion
```

### [Wikipedia](https://www.wikipedia.org/)

[Multi-agent system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-agent_system)